# How can I configure datepicker so its not possible to pick dates less the current day?

Tags: javascript, jquery, datepicker

I am using Datepicker and I wonder how I can configure so users cant pick less the current day?

Solved: `$("selector").datepicker({ minDate: "+0D" });`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Are you using jquery-ui's datepicker? it has an option for your needs (minDate)

http://jqueryui.com/demos/datepicker/

btw, You will have to verify input on server side, data could be spoofed